# How to use FontAwesome Free Font in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, font-awesome, extrafont

I try to plot a certain glyph using `extrafont` (on Windows 10):

```r
library(extrafont)
library(ggplot2)
loadfonts()

ft <- fonttable()

ft[grepl("Awesome", ft$FontName), c("FullName", "FamilyName", "FontName")]

#                          FullName                    FamilyName                   FontName
# 367 Font Awesome 5 Brands Regular Font Awesome 5 Brands Regular FontAwesome5Brands-Regular
# 368     Font Awesome 5 Free Solid     Font Awesome 5 Free Solid     FontAwesome5Free-Solid

ggplot() +
 geom_label(aes(x = 1, y = 1,  label = "\uf0f3"), 
 family = "Font Awesome 5 Free Solid", size = 16) +
 theme_minimal()
```

This works as expected:

[image: ggplot with a FontAwesome Bell symbol]

However, if I try to use another Unicode I just get an empty box:

```r
ggplot() +
 geom_label(aes(x = 1, y = 1,  label = "\uf1fd"), 
 family = "Font Awesome 5 Free Solid", size = 16) +
 theme_minimal()
```

[image: ggplot with an empty box instead of a FontAwesome symbol]

For all it is worth, I am using this [FontAwesome CheatSheet](https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/free/solid) to get the Unicode hex values.

Why is it not working?

### Update

@Pedro was suggetsing in the comments that it may have something to do with the Fontawesome version, so I looked up the `v4` Unicodes, here's what I got:

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)

doc <- "https://fontawesome.com/v4/cheatsheet/" %>% 
  read_html()

unicodes <- doc %>% 
  html_elements(".row .fa+span") %>% 
  html_text2() 

fa <- unicodes %>% 
  str_subset(fixed("(alias)"), TRUE) %>% 
  str_extract("[0-9a-f]+") %>% 
  paste0("0x", .) %>% 
  map_chr(intToUtf8) %>% 
  tibble(label = .) %>% 
  mutate(x = (seq_along(label) - 1) %/% ceiling(sqrt(length(label)))) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(y = seq_along(label) - 1)

ggplot(fa) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y,  label = label), 
             family = "Font Awesome 5 Free Solid", size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y,  label = label), 
            family = "Font Awesome 5 Brands Regular", size = 3, color = "red") +
  
  theme_void()
```

[image: A plot with all fontawesome glpyhs found on the cheatsheet. We see that several of the glyphs are not rendered]

### Session Info

> ```
> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8   
> [3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
> [5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8    
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] ggplot2_3.4.0  extrafont_0.18
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.9       bslib_0.4.2      compiler_4.2.2   pillar_1.8.1    
>  [5] later_1.3.0      jquerylib_0.1.4  tools_4.2.2      digest_0.6.31   
>  [9] jsonlite_1.8.4   lifecycle_1.0.3  tibble_3.1.8     gtable_0.3.1    
> [13] pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.0.6      DBI_1.1.3        shiny_1.7.3     
> [17] cli_3.5.0        fastmap_1.1.0    Rttf2pt1_1.3.8   withr_2.5.0     
> [21] dplyr_1.0.10     generics_0.1.3   sass_0.4.4       vctrs_0.5.1     
> [25] tidyselect_1.2.0 grid_4.2.2       glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1        
> [29] fansi_1.0.3      extrafontdb_1.0  magrittr_2.0.3   scales_1.2.1    
> [33] promises_1.2.0.1 ellipsis_0.3.2   htmltools_0.5.4  assertthat_0.2.1
> [37] mime_0.12        xtable_1.8-4     colorspace_2.0-3 httpuv_1.6.6    
> [41] utf8_1.2.2       munsell_0.5.0    cachem_1.0.6
> ```

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac?

Comment: Ah thanks, will update the question to clarify that. It is Windows.

Comment: Font Awesome has changed quite a bit across versions, mainly by addition of glyphs. Check that the cheatsheet and the version of the font match each other. The problem may be as simple as this.

Comment: The cheatsheet is for version 5, version 4 has only half the number of icons

Comment: Hmm, I must admit that I have no clue which FA version my font is (I played so much with the fonts and `extrafont` that I cannot remember from which R package I got the font from), but the name in `fonttable` would indicate that it is version 5, isn‘t it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling all Font Awesome Fonts from my machine and re-installing them from the [source](https://fontawesome.com/v5/download), all glyphs could be rendered properly.

I just needed to install the webfonts (not the desktop version), because only the webfont comes in `ttf` format, while the desktop only ships the `otf` which cannot be read by  `extrafont::font_import`.